# Wich is the theorem of existence and uniqueness?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I have to enounce and prove the theorem of existence and uniqueness of the problem  $$\begin{cases} u_t +v\cdot\nabla u =f(x,t)-\gamma u, & u(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^n \times (0,\infty), \\ u(x,0)=g(x), & x\in\mathbb{R}^n,  \end{cases} $$ where $\gamma >0$, and $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are constants, $g\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $f\in C(\mathbb{R}^n\times [0,\infty))$ but I don´t know where find the theorem and an idea of the proof. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to find the theorem, because it just says that there is one solution to the problem. To prove uniqueness the usual method is to suppose there are two solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$, and prove they are equal. To do this, find the equation satisfied by the function $w = u_1-u_2$, and show that equation has only the solution with $w$ identically zero. The process of doing that will give you clues about how to show existence.

If you need more hint, the $w$ equation is $w_t+v\cdot\nabla w = -\gamma w$, with $w(x,0) = 0$.

If you need more hint, recognize that the left hand side of the $w$ equation is a directional derivative in the direction of the vector $(v,1)$ in the $(x,t)$ space.